# R: Subset vector by names

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a vector with different names and its values. It is called composite:

```
GSM12    GSM13   GSM15   GSM16  GSM17
0.1234   9.345   8.888   5.345  1.234
```

And I have a second vector with names which are important.I only want those names with its values. The other names could be deleted. The vector is called biopsies.

```
GSM12  GSM15   GSM16
```

The result should be like this:

```
GSM12    GSM15   GSM16
0.1234   8.888   5.345
```

I tried the subset() function but it didn't work.
I also tried this:

```
composite[apply(sapply(biopsies, grepl, composite), 1, any)]
```

But it also didn't work.
So how can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: If it's a named vector and a vector of names, `composite[biopsies]` should work. If it doesn't work, then you should make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) so that we can tell what data structures you have.

Comment: It may not be an elegant alternative, but have you tried something with `ifelse`?

Comment: @Gregor Thank you! That's it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- c(0.1234,   9.345,   8.888,  5.345,  1.234)
names(x) <- c("GSM12",  "GSM13",   "GSM15",   "GSM16",  "GSM17")
y <- c("GSM12", "GSM15",  "GSM16")
```

as @Gregor mentioned:

```
x[y]

 GSM12  GSM15  GSM16 
0.1234 8.8880 5.3450
```